# Spring MongoRepository Get Aggregation count

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data-mongodb 2.0.8 release, and I needed to get the counts of employees in a department of a specific company. Below is the equivalent query if it will be queried in MySQL.

**MySQL**

```
select 
    departmentId, count(employeeId)
from employees
where companyCode = 'ACME'
group by departmentId
```

**MongoDb**

```
db.employees.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        "companyCode": "ACME"
      }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            _id:"$departmentId", 
            count:{$sum:1}
        }
    }
])
```

My problem is, how will I convert this into MongoRepository code something like in JPA. Please see the code below:

```
public interface EmployeeDao extends MongoRepository<Employee, String> {

    Employee findFirstByName(String name);
    Employee findFirstByDepartmentId(String departmentId);
    List<Employee> findEmployeesByCompanyCodeAndDepartmentId(String companyCode, String departmentId);
    List<Employee> findEmployeesByDepartmentId(String departmentId);
    Long countByCompanyCode(String companyCode);
    Long countByDepartmentId(String departmentId);

    // FIXME:
    /*  How will I convert this into MongoRepository code, like above?

        MySQL:
        select 
            departmentId, count(employeeId)
        from employees
        where companyCode = 'ACME'
        group by departmentId

        MongoDb:
        db.employees.aggregate([
            {
              $match: {
                "companyCode": "ACME"
              }
            },
            {
                "$group" : {
                    _id:"$departmentId", 
                    count:{$sum:1}
                }
            }
        ])
    */

}
```

**Update (What works for my case):**

I found the following code working for my case, but I am not sure if this is acceptable or there is a lot better way to do (by best practice).

```
...
        String companyCode =  ACME";
        MatchOperation filterCompany = match(new Criteria("companyCode").is(companyCode));
        GroupOperation groupCountByDepartmentId = group("departmentId").count().as("total");
        SortOperation sortByCountDesc = sort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "total"));
        ProjectionOperation projectToMatchModel = project()
                .andExpression("_id").as("departmentId")
                .andExpression("total").as("count");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation
                .newAggregation(filterCompany, groupCountByDepartmentId, sortByCountDesc, projectToMatchModel);
        AggregationResults<DepartmentCount> groupResults =
                m_mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Employee.class, DepartmentCount.class);
        List<DepartmentCount> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
...
```

**DepartmentCount:**

```
public class DepartmentCount {

    private String departmentId;
    private Integer count;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AggregationOperations similar as follows:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfig.class);
MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate"); 

List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperations = new ArrayList<AggregationOperation>();
aggregationOperations.add(new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("country").is("tigo")));
aggregationOperations.add(new UnwindOperation(Fields.field("myDetails")));
aggregationOperations.add(new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("myDetails.type").is("health")));
aggregationOperations.add(new SortOperation(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "myDetails.datetime")));
AggregationResults<AggregateFactoryResult> result = mongoOperation.aggregate(new Aggregation(aggregationOperations), "gui_data", AggregateFactoryResult.class)
```

Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140491/how-to-create-an-aggregation-from-a-list-of-aggregationoperation-in-spring-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the @Aggregation annotation in a MongoRepository definition to achieve the effect as shown in this unrelated example:

```
  @Aggregation({
      "{$match: { $and : [" +
          "{'keys.k' : 'conversationId', 'keys.v': ?0}, " +
          "{'keys.k' : 'productKey', 'keys.v': ?1 }, " +
          "{'keys.k' : 'tenantId', 'keys.v': ?2}, " +
          "]}}",
      "{'$unwind' : '$messages'}",
      "{'$replaceRoot' : {newRoot: '$messages'}}",
      "{'$match' : { 'direction' :  'INBOUND' }}",
      "{'$match' : { 'views.viewerId' : {'$nin' : [?3]}}}",
      "{'$count' :  'total'}"
  })
  AggregationCount countUnreadMessages(String conversationId,
                                 ProductKey productKey,
                                 UUID tenantId,
                                 UUID userId);
```